# Google developer console has error, thinks I have two expansion files, but should be one

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, developer-console

It thinks my two expansions files are:

main.3.com.jenny.test.obb (49.7 MB)
patch.2.com.jenny.test.obb (49.7 MB)

But, I only uploaded one .obb file, and it wasn't the one labeled "patch".  Additionally, if I try to modify the app at all, I get an error saying it cannot delete the 2nd version because the third version relies on it.  I can't modify anything!

Am I correct that this extra "patch" file is wrong?  If it is, how do I remove it? I manually increased my version (it was originally doing it for version 2, with a patch of 1), and upload a new file, it doesn't help at all.

My .obb and .apk are being generated through Unity, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the same error last week.  The obb file was added twice.

Since you can't remove the patch file for an apk that is already uploaded, you have to upload a new apk.

I recommend you to increase the build-number of your Project, build the splitted apk+obb again and upload them again to the console.

Be sure to add the new obb as expansion file and that no "patch"-file is selected (since you won't be able to change it later)

Comment: I didn't even see the patch drop down when trying to reupload everything, thanks for pointing it out to me!